# Use of greater and less than signs together in mysql query <>

Tags: mysql, sql

What does the `<>` sign mean in MySQL? I saw it in a query, and could not understand what it is.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It means not equal, so these two are equivalent

```
a != b
a <> b
```

Comment: Why have both though?  Is there a reason people would use `<>` over `!=` or vice verse?

Answer (score 6):

Use != operator instead. <> is some oldy goldy way of operating NOT EQUAL TO.

Answer (score 3):

It means 'Not Equal' just as `!=` means 'Not Equal'.
Literally the symbols mean less than and greater than.  Since those two operators are mutually exclusive, putting them together is an impossibility and therefore, NOT EQUAL.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same thing as `!=`. You could read `<>` as "less-than or greater-than".

Comment: You could perhaps read it as "less than *or* greater than (and therefore not equal to)". How could something be both less than and greater than something?